# Bootstrap 3 carousel is not working - whats the conflict?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Working on a new homepage layout for http://beckertime.com/ trying to get the carousel to work.

This is default bootstrap stuff and its not working:

http://beckertime.com/test-carousel/

What am I missing?

Comment: Hmmm, your carousel works for me. You need to give more info than "not working" Also, you need to post code, not just a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get sure that you use this scripts: Then there shouldnt any problems, may you have to initialize in Javascript manually:

```
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel();
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This is the markup:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div> <!-- Carousel -->
```